# In swift, how to perform a segue with .crossDissolve animation?

Tags: swift, animation, segue, fade

In my first view controller, i try to perform a segue after an animation with alpha method.
I specify in the segue, that the modalTransitionStyle is .crossDissolve
but he didn't do it. he performs like push method.

The two viewControllers are under navigationController and are in the same storyboard, but in two differents views.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class AnimationPageDeDemarrageController: UIViewController {
    
    var personne = PersonneController()
    
    @IBOutlet var slogan: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var vueDuSlogan: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var vueBlancheDuSlogan: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var vueBlanche: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var logo: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.vueBlanche.alpha = 0
        self.slogan.alpha = 0
        self.vueDuSlogan.alpha = 0
        self.vueBlancheDuSlogan.alpha = 0
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.faireApparaitreLaPage()
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    }
    
    private func faireApparaitreLaPage() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, animations: {
            self.vueBlanche.alpha = 1.0
            self.slogan.alpha = 1
            self.vueDuSlogan.alpha = 1
            self.vueBlancheDuSlogan.alpha = 1
        }, completion: {
            done in
            if done {
                self.segueVersMenuController()
            }
        })
    }
    
    // segue vers MenuController
    private func segueVersMenuController() {
        //Segue vers la page menuViewController
          let menuViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "MenuViewController") as? MenuViewController
        menuViewController?.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        menuViewController?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            menuViewController?.personne = personne

         self.navigationController?.pushViewController(menuViewController!, animated: true)
    }

}
```

i have tried another type of segue, and the app craches.
Here is the code:

```
    private func presentMenuViewController() {
        let menuViewController = MenuViewController()
        menuViewController.personne = personne
        menuViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        menuViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        present(menuViewController, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: Naming a view controller "versMenuViewControllerSegue" is very confusing. It's not a segue, it's a view controller. You should get rid of the "Segue" part of that variable name.

Comment: @DuncanC ok i will rename it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question, and here is the code of the function to use instead of segueVersMenuController() :

```
private func fadeTransition() {
        let transition: CATransition = CATransition()
        transition.duration = 1.75
        transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeOut)
        transition.type = CATransitionType.fade
        self.navigationController!.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)

        let menuViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuViewController") as! MenuViewController
        menuViewController.personne = self.personne
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(menuViewController, animated: false)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

the `.modalTransitionStyle` property is only for **modal** transitions. A push is not a modal transition.

You will need to create a custom subclass of UIStoryboardSegue.

Comment: but why my second solution crashes the app ?

Comment: Creating a view controller using code like ` let menuViewController = MenuViewController()` is almost always the wrong way to do it. That creates a view controller without loading any of it's views. You should use the UIStoryboard `instantiateViewController(identifier:)` call from your first version to create your view controller in your second solution.

Comment: I don't have an example of a custom push segue. You should be able to find sample code online though.